# Issue with shader execution flow on PowerVR GPU

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I've encountered a problem which I believe is related to optimization of GLSL compilation of PowerVR GPUs. On Adreno and Tegra GPUs fragment shader works just fine, but on PowerVR (Motorola Droid) it produces incorrect result in conditional statement.
I've fixed the problem by changing conditional statement in fragment shader code. Instead of calling `return` in block for `if` statement I've added `else` block and it works OK on PowerVR now.

Logic of both shaders is absolutely identical, `gl_FragColor` is set in both cases.
Please explain this behavior of PowerVR OpenGL driver so I can avoid problems in future. Why does it handle conditional statements this way?

Here is the old fragment shader, which works incorrectly on PowerVR GPUs:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 vViewVec;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D sTexturePumpkin;

void main(void)
{
const float sheen = 0.68;
const float noiseScale = 0.05;
const float furriness = 10.0;
const vec4 lightDir = vec4(0.267260, 0.267260, -0.925820, 0.0);

  vec4 color = texture2D(sTexturePumpkin, vTextureCoord/*vec2(0.0,0.0)*/);
  if(vTextureCoord.y > 0.7) { // in this case PowerVR displays incorrect color
     gl_FragColor = color;
     return;
  }

  float diffuse = 0.5 * (1.0 + dot(vNormal, vec3(lightDir.x, lightDir.y, -lightDir.z)));
  float cosView = clamp(dot(normalize(vViewVec), vNormal), 0.0, 1.0);
  float shine = pow(1.0 - cosView * cosView, furriness);

  gl_FragColor = (color + sheen * shine) * diffuse; // in this case PowerVR works correctly
}
```

The new fragment shader code, which works fine on both Adreno and PowerVR GPU:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 vViewVec;
varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D sTexturePumpkin;

void main(void)
{
const float sheen = 0.68;
const float noiseScale = 0.05;
const float furriness = 10.0;
const vec4 lightDir = vec4(0.267260, 0.267260, -0.925820, 0.0);

  vec4 color = texture2D(sTexturePumpkin, vTextureCoord/*vec2(0.0,0.0)*/);
  if(vTextureCoord.y > 0.7) {
     gl_FragColor = color;
  }
  else {
    float diffuse = 0.5 * (1.0 + dot(vNormal, vec3(lightDir.x, lightDir.y, -lightDir.z)));
    float cosView = clamp(dot(normalize(vViewVec), vNormal), 0.0, 1.0);
    float shine = pow(1.0 - cosView * cosView, furriness);
    gl_FragColor = (color + sheen * shine) * diffuse;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like a driver bug. Driver bugs, being bugs, aren't really something you can "explain". They just happen, and you deal with them.

Comment: You can use vec3(lightDir.xy, -lightDir.z).

Comment: @NicolBolas I believe that it's not a bug in GLSL compiler but the specificity of PowerVR GPU tile based rendering and execution of fragment shaders. I'd like to get some critics on my answer below.

Comment: @keaukraine: No. The OpenGL specification is very clear about the behavior of what happens after `discard` and `return`. And if PowerVR's compiler doesn't/can't generate PowerVR shader code that does what the specification says it does, then it is a *driver bug*.

Comment: @NicolBolas In GLSL specs it is explicitly said that shader doesn't stop execution on `discard`: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Core_Language#Control_flow I believe the same is applicable for `return` -- because of batch processing of fragment shaders.

Comment: @keaukraine: It doesn't *stop* execution, but it *does* prevent any results from those executions from being visible. It must behave *as if* execution had stopped. If that's not happening, that's a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so after deeper investigation I have found that it's not a bug of shader compiler but a specific way of processing fragment shaders execution. It is generally a bad idea to put a simple `discard;` or `return;` statement with some code coming after it. It still can be executed and cause unpredictable result.

There are some articles that explains this behavior applicable to `discard;` statement, and as I see the similar behavior can happen with `return;` too.
Please read one here: http://people.freedesktop.org/~idr/OpenGL_tutorials/03-fragment-intro.html#infinite-loop
As is it said here, in certain cases you can even achieve infinite loop by incorrect usage of `discard;`.

Fragment shaders are executed by GPU not for a single texel at a time, usually in batches of 2x2 pixels. And this parallel running of fragment shader can cause code after `return;`.

So, for fragment shader to handle `if` statements correctly, you have to always use `else` in `if` operators, not simply exiting function by `return;` or `discard;`. This is exactly what I've done.